# Owl Carousel Won't Autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

I'm using the Owl Carousel on my site. According to their documentation, this piece of JavaScript should work:

```
<script>
$("#intro").owlCarousel({

// Most important owl features

//Autoplay
autoPlay : 5000,
stopOnHover : false
)}
</script>
```

But for some reason it will not autoplay. Here is the HTML of the slider:

```
<div id="intro" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item first">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="carousel-caption-left colour-white">
            <h2>Title Text</h2>
            <h1>Sub title text here.</h1>
            <p>If you like you can even add a sentence or two here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item second">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption-left colour-white">
          <h2>Title Text</h2>
          <h1>Sub title text here.</h1>
          <p>If you like you can even add a sentence or two here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item third">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption-left colour-white">
          <h2>Title Text</h2>
          <h1>Sub title text here.</h1>
          <p>If you like you can even add a sentence or two here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 89):

Yes, its a typing error.

Write

> autoPlay

not

> autoplay

The autoplay-plugin code defines the variable as "autoPlay".

Comment: I was having this issue until I saw your post. I had set "autoPlay", but actually changing it to "autoplay" made it work for me. Weird.

Comment: thanks, even on their own page its typing as lower case.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have to say though that the official doc states it with lowercase, so it might depend on the OwlCarousel version you are using.

Comment: The version does matter. Owl Carousel 2 uses "autoplay".  Older version uses "autoPlay".  Also worth noting, in version 2 you must use "autoplayTimeout" to set the speed of the autoplay features. In older versions, this was actually set by the "autoPlay" option.

Comment: This typo is even on their site. http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/autoplay.html wasted time :(:(

Comment: Thanks mate, my version is 2.3.4 and the word is autoplay.

Comment: Can't believe codpen made this little mistake :(

Comment: 2022 and this post is still useful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 43):

You are may be on the wrong owl's doc version.

```
autoPlay is for 1st version

autoplay is for 2nd version
```

Comment: Link only answers are not a good practice. please add then in comments and not as answers..

Comment: Consider removing first link as it is no longer linking to desired place. Github for v 1: https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel

Answer (score 22):

Changing autoplay to autoPlay alone did not work for me. What did the trick was to add autoplaySpeed and autoplayTimeout properties and set them to the same value, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
    owl.owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoPlaySpeed: 5000,
        autoPlayTimeout: 5000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true
    });
});
```

Here's a working demo: [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/mixodusayi/edit?html,js,output)

More info about this can be found here: https://github.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/issues/234

Comment: I can confirm this is working with the latest version !

Comment: You need a comma after `autoPlayTimeout: 5000` to get `autoPlayTimeout: 5000,`

Answer (score 9):

add this

```
owl.trigger('owl.play',6000);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should set both **autoplay** and **autoplayTimeout** properties. I used this code, and it works for me:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                navigation: false,
                margin: 10,
                responsive: {
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    },
                    600: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    1000: {
                        items: 2
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 5):

With version 2.3.4, you need the to add the owl.autoplay.js plugin.
Then do the following

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
   items:1, //how many items you want to display
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:10000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true
});
```

Comment: @createscape Are you sure owl.autoplay.js is not cached in your browser. Maybe you can try another browser and see if it would still work.

Answer (score 4):

This code should work for you

```
$("#intro").owlCarousel ({

        slideSpeed : 800,
        autoPlay: 6000,
        items : 1,
        stopOnHover : true,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,1],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,1],
        itemsTablet :   [768,1],
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a Typing Error,

```
<script>
$("#intro").owlCarousel({

// Most important owl features

//Autoplay
autoPlay : 5000,
stopOnHover : false
)} ----- TYPO
</script>
```

It should be-

```
<script>
$("#intro").owlCarousel({

// Most important owl features

//Autoplay
autoPlay : 5000,
stopOnHover : false
}) ----- Correct
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Javascript should be

```
<script>
$("#intro").owlCarousel({

// Most important owl features

//Autoplay
autoplay: false,
autoplayTimeout: 5000,
autoplayHoverPause: true
)}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case **autoPlay** not working but **autoplay** is working fine

I only used this

```
<script src="plugins/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

no owl.autoplay.js is need it & my owl carousel version is *@version 2.0.0*

hope this thing help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Owl Carousel version matters a lot, as of now (**2nd Aug 2020**) the version is `2.3.4` and the right options for autoplay are:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay : true,
    autoplayTimeout: 3000,//Autoplay interval timeout.
    loop:true,//Infinity loop. Duplicate last and first items to get loop illusion.
    items:1 //The number of items you want to see on the screen.
});
```

Read more Owl [configurations](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html)

Answer (score 1):

Setting `autoPlay: true` didn't work for me.
But on setting `autoPlay: 5000` it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you using v1.3.3 then use following property

```
autoPlay : 5000
```

Or 
using latest version then use following property

```
autoPlay : true
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you need to call the owl.autoplay.js.
2. this code works for me : owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[1000]);

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couln't find the solution. Finally I realized, that with owlcarousel ver. 2.3.4 I have to include not only owl.carousel.js, but owl.autoplay.js file too.