# OWL 2 Carousel Auto Play Not Working

Tags: owl-carousel

I have two slides going. I was using OWL 1 and it worked great. I would like the infinite loop, so moved to OWL 2.

The following code works great. The slides stay in sync, but autoplay never starts. I have to drag the slides or show the navigation and click next/prev.

Hoping the answer is pretty obvious to someone with more experience.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var carousel_1 = $('#the_carousel'),
carousel_2 = $('#the_carousel_content');

carousel_2.on('change.owl.carousel', function(event) {
carousel_1.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [event.item.index,100,true]);

});

carousel_1.owlCarousel({
items:1,
loop:true,
autoPlay: true,
autoplayTimeout: 100,
slideBy: 1,
autoplaySpeed: 100,
 rewindNav: false
});

carousel_2.owlCarousel({
items:1,
loop:true,
autoPlay: false,
autoplaySpeed: 100,
autoplayTimeout: 100,
nav:false,
slideBy: 1,
rewindNav: false
});

});
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Consider the typo at:

```
autoPlay: true,
```

it must be:

```
autoplay: true,
```

And for the ones who has downloaded the development version of library must be careful that the autoplay plugin is not included as user em2 said.

Answer (score 0):

this guy had the same problem: [Owl Carousel Will Not Autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351046/owl-carousel-will-not-autoplay)

you need to manually add autoplay.js library from owl site

```
<script src="owl/js/owl.autoplay.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried that. No luck. Also, the autoplay is already in the owl.carousel.js file.