# Owl carousel Auto Play not working properly?

Tags: jquery, html, slider, carousel, owl-carousel

I am getting problem with owl carousel 'auto play' functionality. I have uploaded and included all the needed files. Its is working properly on load. Auto Play works perfectly. But when I hover on any of the slide it stops(& I want to stop on hover). And when I release the mouse it didn't play again. plus when I switch between different tabs of the browser and come back to the tab where the carousel is open it permanently stops at that point too. I need to drag it with mouse click or mouse ball then it play again.

Can't figure out whats the problem. I have consulted the official "Owl carousel" website and these threads as well [Thread 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430514/owl-2-carousel-auto-play-not-working), [Thread 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351046/owl-carousel-will-not-autoplay), [Thread 04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678720/owl-carousel-wont-autoplay). Tried and applied all the solutions provided in these threads. Nothing changed.

**Here is my code.**

```
<section id="demos">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">             
          <img src="carousel-03.png" alt="Owl Image">
          <h2>Logo Design</h2>
          <p>Our logo designs are unique enough to get you the trademark and compelling enough to help you get clients. Get a logo done by us and see for yourself.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">              
          <img src="carousel-05.png" alt="Owl Image">
          <h2>Stationery Design</h2>
          <p>We design business cards and stationery which Convey the professionalism and seriousness of your business to your customers.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="carousel-02.png" alt="Owl Image">
          <h2>Flyers &amp; Brochures</h2>
          <p>We design brochures which depict your services in an impressive way to both current and potential clientele.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="carousel-01.png" alt="Owl Image">
          <h2>Apps Design</h2>
          <p>We design Apps which depict your services in an impressive way to both current and potential clientele.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">              
          <img src="carousel-04.png" alt="Owl Image">
          <h2>Labels and Packaging</h2>
          <p>We design Labels and Packaging which depict your services in an impressive way to both current and potential clientele.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**This is my Js**

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
      owl.owlCarousel({
         loop: true,
         nav: false,
         navSpeed: 2000,
         slideSpeed : 2000,
         dots: false,
         dotsSpeed: 2000,
         lazyLoad: false,
         autoplay: true,
         autoplayHoverPause: true,
         autoplayTimeout: 5000,
         autoplaySpeed:  800,
         margin: 0,
         stagePadding: 0,
         freeDrag: false,
         mouseDrag: true,
         touchDrag: true,
         slideBy: 1,
         fallbackEasing: "linear",
         responsiveClass: true,
         navText: [ "previous", "next" ],
         responsive: {
            0: {
               items: 1,
               nav: false
            },
            600: {
               items: 2,
               nav: false
            },
            1000: {
               items: 3,
               nav: false,
               margin: 20
            }
          }
       });
       owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
         if (e.deltaY>0) {
            owl.trigger('next.owl');
         } else {
            owl.trigger('prev.owl');
         }
         e.preventDefault();
      });
   })
</script>
```

Here are the files included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/owl.autoplay.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.autorefresh.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/highlight.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a default can't be provided as an option so you need to make your own function

declare a variable at the start

```
var block = false;
```

Now first we will go for mouse over functon

```
$(".owl-item").mouseenter(function(){
 if(!block) {
  block = true;
  owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
  block = false;
  }
});
```

Now using the same above variable we will make mouse leave function

```
$(".owl-item").mouseleave(function(){
 if(!block) {
  block = true;
  owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[1000])
  block = false;
 }
});
```

Hope its the answer to your question!

Comment: Thankyou very much. This is  what i was looking for