# How to run autoplay video and mute the sound?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, owl-carousel-2

How to run autoplay video and mute the sound for owl carousel 2?

My code - https://jsfiddle.net/ufqp8Lku/

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  merge: true,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  video: true,
  lazyLoad: true,
  center: true,
  responsive: {
    480: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 1
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel,
.owl-carousel .item-video {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item-video" data-merge="1">
    <a class="owl-video" href="https://vimeo.com/23924346"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-video" data-merge="1">
    <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpxsRwnRwCQ"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-video" data-merge="1">
    <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBu_jxT1PkA"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This carousel is adding your video as an **iframe** in the html. You need to add **autoplay** and **muted** attributed on those like a video but its little tricky. This might help you https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors

Comment: possile dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678720/owl-carousel-wont-autoplay

Comment: $('.owl-video-play-icon').click() this could help you also

Comment: @Gaurav Chaudhary This question is not a duplicate, because I need autoplay video, not autoplay slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can work around the cross origin issues I'm getting in jsfiddle this will solve your problem:

```
function muteCurrentYoutubeVideo(){
    var tempId =  'yt-' + +new Date();
    var activeFrame = document.querySelector(".owl-item.active iframe");
    activeFrame.setAttribute('id', tempId);
    var player;


    player = new YT.Player(tempId, {
        events: {
            'onReady': function(){ 
                player.mute();
                player.playVideo();
                activeFrame.setAttribute('id', '');
            }
        }
   });
}

function toggleOwlVideos(){
    // set required elements here.
    var currentSlide = document.querySelector(".owl-item.active");
    var playBtn = currentSlide.querySelector(".owl-video-play-icon");
    var frame = currentSlide.querySelector("iframe");
    var loading = Boolean(frame);

    // if playBtn found and carousel is not loading the vimeo frame
    if (playBtn && !loading){
       playBtn.click(); // toggle play state
    }

    if (frame){ // if vimeos frame is ready
        frame.contentWindow.postMessage('{"method":"setVolume", "value":0}', '*'); // set value to 0
        muteCurrentYoutubeVideo();
    } else {
       setTimeout(toggleOwlVideos, 300); // try again in 300ms.
    } 
}

var owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({ /* ... */ });

owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
     // executed whenever owlcarousel changes.
     // the timeout(0) is required unfortunately because
     // otherwise this gets executed before the slide has
     // successfully changed.
     setTimeout(toggleOwlVideos, 0);
})
```

And for the volume toggle button:

```
$(".mute-toggle").on("click", function(){
      var tempId =  'yt-' + +new Date();
      var activeFrame = document.querySelector(".owl-item.active iframe");
      activeFrame.setAttribute('id', tempId);
      var player;


      player = new YT.Player(tempId, {
          events: {
              'onReady': function(){ 
                  if (player.isMuted()){
                      player.unMute();
                  } else {
                      player.mute();
                  }
                  activeFrame.setAttribute('id', '');
              }
          }
      });
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/05t1ryje/

I'm using postMessage to communicate with the iFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, autostart works, but the sound does not vanish

Comment: Can you check what happens if you don't use jsfiddle but just add that code to your page? Might be a problem when running it inside nested iframes. If that also doesn't work, we'll have to use a different approach to embed these videos (e.g. manually - not using owlCarousel's own video implementation).

Comment: I'll fix it, can you please enable the youtube JS API? You have it in your HTML but commented. Then I can change my script accordingly to make it work.

Comment: Hey bro, sorry for being late I was driving home :). I updated my code, it should now mute your video on slide change and autostart it. I tested it by dumping the `muteCurrentYoutubeVideo` function into the console and running it manually. Can you confirm?

Comment: Thanks, now works fine. Another question is the VOLUMEUP button, but this button only works for 1 video slide. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Because the other youtube Videos are removed from the page if you change the slide, as soon as owlCarousel puts them in the Front they start to load again with sound. Is that what you mean or do you want to support multiple owlCarousel sliders on a single page?

Comment: I would like the ability to add an on / off volume button

Comment: I updated the code to make the on/off toggle button work.Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140028/discussion-between-praszyk-and-dmitriy).

Comment: Vimeo Not loading if any possible to play vimeo Videos

Comment: Hey, can you add post a code sample so I can take a look at it? It might be related to vimeo JS itself.

Answer (score 1):

Call the jQuery function play() in the callback afterAction:

```
afterAction: function(current) {
        current.find('video').get(0).play();
    }
```

Or even this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                $(".active .owl-video-play-icon").trigger("click");
            }, 1000);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.owl-dot', function() {
        if ($('.owl-item.active').hasClass('owl-video-playing')) {} else {
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    $(".active .owl-video-play-icon").trigger("click");
                }, 1000);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Example:

http://codepen.io/vishpatel93/pen/gmqzQv

Comment: Thanks, autoplay video works, but how to turn off the sound of the video so that it works in the background?

Comment: Want to mute all ?

Comment: How to remove the volume of the video, but with the ability to turn the volume on?

Comment: Use prop to toggle the mute property. May need an additional button and z-index if video going to have overlay

Comment: example for video html 5 - https://jsfiddle.net/ovcmh686/, how to do this for iframe youtube, iframe vimeo?

Comment: For vimeo you can send a postmessage to set voice to 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139773/discussion-between-vaishal-patel-and-dmitriy).

Comment: Vimeo Not loading if any possible to play vimeo Videos